# No encuentro el error: Parse error:

Tags: php

Hola me sale este error y no encuentro en que esta mal

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
>   expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number
>   (T_NUM_STRING) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\SIE\HorasExtras\Lista_horasextras.php on line 154

Código:

```
 echo "<button  class=\"btn btn-info\" id=\"editarConsulta\" onclick=\"cambiarContenidos('#contenidos','HorasExtras/edita_horasextras.php?accion=editar&id=<?php echo $rowActividades['Id_horasextras']; ?>' );\">";
```

Comment: tenes un echo dentro de un echo con una variable que intenta expandirse por las comillas dobles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de escribir un código que realmente hace daño a la vista y que provocará dolores de cabeza para analizarlo, puedes usar variables, por ejemplo:

```
id=$rowActividades['Id_horasextras'];
$onClick="onclick=\"cambiarContenidos('#contenidos','HorasExtras/edita_horasextras.php?accion=editar&id=$id' );\"";

echo "<button  class=\"btn btn-info\" id=\"editarConsulta\" $onClick>";
```

Salida:

```html
<button  class="btn btn-info" id="editarConsulta" onclick="cambiarContenidos('#contenidos','HorasExtras/edita_horasextras.php?accion=editar&id=1' );">
```

De ese modo:

- el código es claro y más elegante
- tienes el `$id` disponible si lo necesitas
- tienes el `$onClick` disponible también si lo necesitas más adelante

**NOTA:** Quizá conviene ponerle texto al botón....

Comment: muchas gracias me funciono de maravilla

Comment: @carlosbecerra Me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) en el Centro de Ayuda.